# Swift add or update Array of item base on unique property id

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm finding effective algorithms that can add array of objects (object is class not struct) into existing array. The requirement is if existing array contains object with same `id`, the function will update that object (change existing object's properties according to updated object). If `object.id` is not included in existing array, the function will simply add that object to the existing array. The return array is consist of new objects and updated object.

Basically only add object if object.id is new. if object.id is already included, it will update object's properties

I have try below

```
func addPhotoArray(_ photos: [Photo], addedPhoto: [Photo]) -> [Photo]{
        var resultArray = photos
        let originalIds = photos.map{$0.id}

        for photo in addedPhoto {
            if !originalIds.contains(photo.id) {
                resultArray.append(photo)
            }
        }
        return resultArray
    }
```

but I'm missing the update requirement. How can I solve the problem?

### Update

Replacing item with index is an option. But not sure whether it its efficient if only 1 or 2 properties changed or nothing changed at all. I'm also thinking of using a `Set`. How to conform to hashable that we can use union function as below

```
extension Photo {
    static func union (left: [Photo],right: [Photo] ) -> [Photo]{
        return Array(Set(left).union(Set(right)))
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Photo, rhs: Photo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary in which the `photo.id` is the key? It would serve your purpose better in my opinion

Comment: Regarding your update, if you want a solution using Hashable you should ask a new question but as I see it you will have a solution where you completely replaces objects.

Comment: thanks you mean using Set we will end up replacing the existing item also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I chose to not use an array of id's but instead used `firstIndex` to find a duplicate photo (I assumed all photos in original array are unique) and if one was found I replaced it with the new version

```
func addPhotoArray(_ photos: [Photo], addedPhoto: [Photo]) -> [Photo]{
    var resultArray = photos

    for photo in addedPhoto {
        if let photoIndex = resultArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == photo.id}) {
            resultArray[photoIndex] = photo
        } else {
            resultArray.append(photo)
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks. replacing with index is an option but wonder if it is efficient if only 1.2 properties is change no nothing change? I'm also adding to question how do we implement Set

Comment: True but it wasn't part of your question so I didn't know how to do it. You could use `first(where:)` instead to get the existing object instead of the index and then update it using some custom merge function.

Comment: let say i have an merge function mutating func updatePhoto(_ photo: Photo, updatedPhoto: Photo). How can we update without total replace?

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this , you have to check attribute by attribute for a change and to possibly update it. And also I would not make such a method a class method so the interface would be `updatePhoto(_ updatedPhoto: Photo)

Comment: thanks i have changed the func signature but where do we put that function in? we are changing only that item but not the the item inside resultArray

Comment: You add that function to the Photo class, I have assumed that this is your class so that you can modify it otherwise you need to go back to your original signature.

Comment: Oop i mean how can we modify this function func addPhotoArray(_ photos: [Photo], addedPhoto: [Photo]) -> [Photo] to reflect the update instead of replace

Comment: This is getting far from the original question, please create a new question in regard to updating/merging

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have created a new question regarding the merge function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831416/swift-add-or-merge-array-of-item-base-on-unique-property-id

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary of type `[YourIdType: YourObjectType]` is your solution. Insertion and retrieving cost is `O(1)`. In your case the worst case complexity will be `O(n)`, where `n = addedArray.count`

More about [Dictionary](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: Do you have an example of how we can implement Dictionary?

Comment: Created a sample for you [here](https://pastebin.com/GLy0Qw2T). Paste it to playground to see how it works.

Comment: Update your answer instead, it's almost impossible to read code in comments section

Comment: I'm trying to read your suggestion in pasterbin. but seem we still end up replace the object instead of update it?

Comment: As you mentioned, your object is a reference type, so it's ok. In general, i would suggest you to restrict from premature optimization. Optimization is necessary after profiling and determining the bottlenecks of your code.

Comment: Thanks. will follow the practice. Actually i'm trying to find a effective way to append new response from server to existing data (add new or merge if require). There a new question here with regarding the merge ability. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831416/swift-add-or-merge-array-of-item-base-on-unique-property-id

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
func addPhotoArray(_ photos: [Photo], addedPhoto: [Photo]) -> [Photo]{
    var resultArray = photos
    for photo in addedPhoto {
        // Search for the object is it already exists
        if let existingPhotoIndex = photos.firstIndex(where: { (tempPhoto) -> Bool in
                return photo.id == tempPhoto.id
            }) {
             resultArray[existingPhotoIndex] = photo // Replace the object 
        }
        else {
            resultArray.append(photo) // Insert new Object
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

You can further improve this if you want.

Comment: This contains both a logical and a compilation error, `photos[existingPhotoIndex] = photo`

Comment: is replacing option is efficient? let say i have an update func like mutating func updatePhoto(_ photo: Photo, updatedPhoto: Photo). How do we update instead of replace? (when only 1.2 properties changed or nothing changed at all. update seem better?)