# Swift add or merge Array of item base on unique property id

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, merge

I'm finding effective algorithms that can add array of objects (object is `class` not `struct`) into existing array. The requirement is if existing array contains object with same `id`, the function will `merge` object (update original object properties if there is any change). If `object.id` is not included in existing array, the function will simply add that object to the existing array. The return array is consist of new objects and updated object.

Basically only add object if object.id is new. If object.id is already included, it will merge the object's properties.

Thanks fellow @Joakim Danielson I have come out with a possible solution to replace duplicate with new one. I'm finding a way to merge instead of replacing:

```
func addPhotoArray(_ photos: [Photo], addedPhoto: [Photo]) -> [Photo]{
    
    var resultArray = photos
    
    for photo in addedPhoto {
        if let photoIndex = resultArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == photo.id}) {
            resultArray[photoIndex] = photo
        } else {
            resultArray.append(photo)
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

I have prepared a `merge` function like bellow in `Photo` class

```
func updatePhoto(_ updatedPhoto: Photo) {
        
        self.title = updatedPhoto.title
        self.owner = updatedPhoto.owner
        self.secret = updatedPhoto.secret
        self.server = updatedPhoto.server
        self.farm = updatedPhoto.farm
        self.ispublic = updatedPhoto.ispublic
        self.isfriend = updatedPhoto.isfriend
        self.isfamily = updatedPhoto.isfamily
        
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `resultArray[photoIndex] = photo` use `resultArray[photoIndex].updatePhoto(photo)`.

Comment: thanks just fix the typo. but will resultArray[photoIndex].updatePhoto(photo) changes the resultArray?

Comment: Yes,it will change.

Comment: is this because Photo is class reference type. if Photo is struct type should be different?

Comment: Yes, it is. If Photo is struct type you will not be able to modify Photo inside Photo until you mark `updatePhoto` function as `mutating func`. In both cases resultArray will be changed.

Comment: thanks for clarify I ask this because first i use struct but then change to class to use Realm database (dont know if it is a good choice)

Comment: In case of class when you call `addPhotoArray(externalPhotosArray...` externalPhotosArray will be modified.
In case of struct when you call `addPhotoArray(externalPhotosArray...` externalPhotosArray will not be modified.